# discord.py on_member_join() isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

beforehand: I tried already a lot of potential fixes which are available on stack overflow. Sadly none of them worked.

Here is the Code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is online')
    return await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=2, name='bla'))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x95efcc, description=f"Welcome! You are the {len(list(member.guild.members))} Member!"),

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")

    embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}", url=f"{member.avatar_url}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")

    embed.timestemp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    channel = bot.get_channel(id=012391238123)

    await channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('Token')
```

The bot logs in but it won't execute on_member_join. Has anybody an idea what might be wrong? on_message works fine.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

didn't help and in discord developer it's also checked (Server Members Intent).
The bot also has administrator privileges

Greetings Eduard

---

Solution in short:

```
imports
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x95efcc, description=f"Welcome to my discord server! You are the {len(list(member.guild.members))} member!")
channel = bot.get_channel(id=12931203123)

await channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: You're using the decorator `@bot.command()` but you're defining `client = discord.Client`
You probably want to change that to `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix', intents=intents)`

Comment: Ouw, yes. I actually have it already like this: 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

I just missed it in my Code above - sorry!

Comment: but did you add the intents in there?

Comment: Is `guild_subscriptions` enabled?

Comment: Guys! Thanks both of you - it worked! :))))

I'll change the code above!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so that's it.
Since you are using `commands.Bot`, the `bot.get_channel` is no longer a function (since it is no longer `discord.Client`). Try using `member.guild.get_channel` instead.

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)